# Animating the border radius in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm unable to animate the borderRadius property in a ReactNative Image, it seems to only re-render the image as the animation completes. It fades out on animation start, and fades back in on animation completion.  This only happens on Android; on iOS the animation plays properly.

I am trying to animate a circle expanding into a square by animating the borderRadius:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        borderRadius: new Animated.Value(ALBUM_CIRCLE_DIAMETER /2)
    };
}

_zoomIn = () => {
    Animated.timing(
        this.state.borderRadius,
        {
            toValue: 0,
            duration: ZOOM_ANIMATION_DURATION_MS,
            easing: Easing.linear
        }
    ).start()
}
```

And the markup:

```
<Animated.Image
    style={[
        styles.albumArtCircle,
        { width: this.state.albumArtWidth },
        { height: this.state.albumArtHeight },
        { borderRadius: this.state.borderRadius },
    ]}
    resizeMode='contain'
    source={require('../images/sampleAlbum.jpg')}>
</Animated.Image>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right! Remove resizeMode property. This will solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

Removing `resizeMode='contain'` made this work.